# How do you say "Take the next right" when giving directions

Tags: grammar

I'm interested to see if anyone can help me out. I was talking to a chinese friend and I was trying to give them directions - however, I was struggling saying the simple phrase in english of "Once you pass the fedex, take the next right".

Would this  be

"你经过Fedex以后， 你马上要右转“  － but I think that this is not quite the meaning I
 am looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can say "你在 Fedex 那邊拐右" or "你往前走到 Fedex, 再拐右"

Edit: Oops, Sorry that I overlooked "the next right".  Then it should be "你往前走, 在 Fedex 之後的(十字)路口拐右."

Comment: But how would it be "the next" right. I'm not asking them to turn right at fedex

Comment: Henry Quick question though - what if the turn was not a fourway stop? Would 十字路口  still work?

Comment: @Stephen: If it is not a fourway stop, simply say "路口".

Answer (score 2):

I think you may wanna say `穿过Fedex(路)后，下个路口右转。`

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: "pass" == "穿过" in mandarin?

Comment: @HenryHO Yes, "穿过" is the same as "经过" ,which both mean "pass", but "穿过" in my opinion sounds more natural. ^.^

Comment: To me, "穿過" sounds as if that Fedex has two entries (or exits) and I need to walk through it.